# Create Canvas in a in different Thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have written a library which does some heavy layouting and graphics rendering. Using an abstraction layer I can change the way the graphics themselves are actually created (GDI, HTML5 etc.). One implementation adds different shapes (Path, Rectangle) and controls (TextBlock) to a canvas and positions them. There are usually about 3000-5000 children created within the canvas.

Now to my actual problem: If I open a file from my WPF window and let the graphics be processed synchronously the UI will block. My goal is to create the WPF tree (canvas + children) on a different thread and add it to the main window as soon it's rendered. Simple on the first thought but a problem using WPF because it requires all controls to be created on the UI thread.

I wanted to ask if there is a common way how to build a canvas on another thread. I've read about the possibility to create freezable objects, freeze them and pass them to the main UI afterwards. The problem: the `TextBlock` class cannot be freezed and this would still require the thousands of objects to be iterated and processed again.

My very last solution would be to build the plain XAML string in my abstraction layer and use the `XamlParser` in the UI thread.

I hope anybody can give me some hints how I could solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can create UI elements in non-UI threads, but it's difficult and probably not worth the effort.  WPF isn't very efficient with large amount of geometry objects like that in general.. here are some ideas:

- Use GDI in a background thread and draw the resulting image in a UI control
- Use a WriteableBitmap (with [this](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) extension)
- Create your own control, override OnRender and try drawing everything directly to the drawingcontext
- Use SlimDx or SharpDx or your own managed C++) and D3dImage to render stuff using DirectX

Comment: When using GDI or WritableBitmap I will loose a lot of great WPF capabilities like zooming and element styling. The DrawingContext does not allow me any async processing/rendering. Using a DirectX wrapper for rendering a 2D image sounds like a bad idea.